# Why is the sha256 hash of a vscode extension different if I download the `latest` version and the actual latest version (e.g. `1.2.3`)

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, nixos

### Problem

When I download an archive from the vscode marketplace with `latest` as version, I get a different sha256 checksum as when I download it with the explicit latest version.

Example from nix repl with the ms-toolsai.jupyter extension:

```
nix-repl> builtins.fetchurl { url = "https://ms-toolsai.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-toolsai/extension/jupyter/latest/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Se
rvices.VSIXPackage"; sha256 = ""; }  
warning: found empty hash, assuming 'sha256-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA='
error: hash mismatch in file downloaded from 'https://ms-toolsai.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-toolsai/extension/jupyter/latest/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage':
         specified: sha256:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
         got:       sha256:0wimki8s5vygbmz0l60r1vbqz5b6wj9c5wd6aippz8wy3rl4c1pf

nix-repl> builtins.fetchurl { url = "https://ms-toolsai.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-toolsai/extension/jupyter/2023.5.1001411100/assetbyname/Microsoft.Visuwarning: found empty hash, assuming 'sha256-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA='
error: hash mismatch in file downloaded from 'https://ms-toolsai.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-toolsai/extension/jupyter/2023.5.1001411100/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage':
         specified: sha256:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
         got:       sha256:0zr607q8w1gfrmbgdldikswg8gw6g5vgs1fsvvvpbpgd7hsg2c4m
```

This happens with multiple extensions but not necesserily with all.

### Background

For nixos, I crawl the latest version of all my used extensions from the api with the `latest` tag and extract the version from the archive with a custom bash script. The script also builds a list of extensions with the explicit versions for nixos to be consumed. Nixos then installs all extensions in my immutable vscode extension directory.

For now I have a workaround which downloads the extension twice: Once with the `latest` version to get the actual version and a second time with the explicit version to get the correct sha256 hash.

### Question(s)

1. Is this a bug with the API or it this an intended behavior?
2. If this is intended, why? Is there some security or other reason behind it?
3. Is there a better way to get the latest version without downloading the extension first?

Answer (score 0):

Just trying it on my machine, to check the sums:

```
$ curl https://ms-toolsai.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-toolsai/extension/jupyter/latest/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage | sha256sum
ee0646681e9ea37f6f54a6f1c292e466958fd70e19180a7e5dcfefa2519c3572  -
```

```
$ curl https://ms-toolsai.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/ms-toolsai/extension/jupyter/2023.5.1001411100/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VSIXPackage | sha256sum
9530f1343ceddd75f7deda05fd7679863ff4b89eb1d1f656cdee058ef001267f  -
```

So it seems that they are simply different files. I can't tell you why that's the case, but you can try to download them yourself and look at the diff. It only seems to be the metadata that differs.

On the subject of actually updating your vscode extensions:

Many vscode extensions are available in nixpkgs, where they use [the following script](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-22.11/pkgs/applications/editors/vscode/extensions/update_installed_exts.sh#L34) to automatically create nix derivations for the extensions that are included. It sounds a lot like your script, and you could probably borrow a thing or two from them.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Actually I used the mentioned script and changed it slightly in a way, that i can handle a plain list of extensions, so I can install all extensions the same way. I believe that this script currently also fails due this issue.